# Graphical corruption of characters in File Manager or Terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line, intel-graphics, hibernate, filemanager

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with graphic driver Intel® 945G x86/MMX/SSE2. Sometimes (I think after using hibernation - not restarting system) I'm getting graphical issue with characters in File Manager or Terminal. I can't imagine what is the source of this problem.

Here is my desktop with graphical corruption, see text characters in browser is fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a rather severe example of the intel text rendering bug that has been around since Natty Narwhal.  The fix usually suggested is to insert the following into /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "DebugWait" "true"
EndSection
```

The Launchpad bug report is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/782855).

It could also be this Intel/Xorg bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1005717][2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1005717) However that is markd "fix released".  Make sure your Ubuntu is fully updated.  Chris.

Comment: Could I create a new file "xorg.conf" if I'm missing it? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can just create the xorg.conf file with the above contents only.  I've done this for my EeePC and it seem to have helped a lot, though I did still see a problem on Firefox tabs once only.

Comment: It does not help :( after using of hibernation instead of turning off system problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

it's  a display problem. maybe a bug. try to use VESA driver

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-vesa
```