# System displaying "E" as "H" (?) from different font (?)

Tags: 14.04, unity, graphics, display, filemanager

This is weird - and it just turned up yesterday. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and fairly vanilla.

As of yesterday, the system wants to display the character `E` as `H`. Here are two examples. First, the native file manager (and also PCManFM, which I use regularly) show it -- although (oddly?) Krusader is fine:

[image: filemanagers]

And all the drop-down menus from the Unity toolbar show the same weirdness:

[image: dropdown]

I've seen an older [Q&A on "graphical corruption"](https://askubuntu.com/q/193590/38585), but (a) those issues should have long been dealt with in 14.04, and (b) this problem started yesterday - I've been running this machine happily for over a year, and 14.04 is the only OS it has had. I don't think there were any obvious upgrades to account for it (I run the updater every morning).

Grateful for any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an actual font that's gone bad, maybe taking a look at that font with something like `gnome-font-viewer` to check, possibly reisntall the font?

But, that's almost exactly what used to happen when I ran earler versions of gnome3 (I think that's still the base for Unity), only it had more letters completely gone and a few other graphic errors here & there. Some programs would look normal, though. Later updated versions of gnome3 were fixed.

I'm suspecting there was an update that's causing this problem now, is there a way you can "roll back" any recent updates (maybe from before the last reboot, in case it could have updated but showed no errors until after a reboot?) and see if the problem goes away? Or first might as well check for any new updates that may fix it?

And trying a different window manager may be a potential workaround, and could verify if it is a WM (gnome3-ish) display issue at least. Openbox is quite small, or possibly xfce4 or icewm, jwm. lxde if you already like pcmanfm, (but I don't see the lxde window manager on it's own).

Comment: In fact, it seems to have been some kind of system glitch - it has happened to me once or twice more (very infrequently) and a simple reboot fixes it each time. Thanks for the other suggestions which might be useful in future.